# Load Data only when tab is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I am rendering the all data into page once(on single url 'http://localhost:9111/sale/').

And showing into different tabs on that page.

```
<div class="tab-base">
             <!--Nav Tabs-->
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo-lft-tab-1">Daily Sale</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo-lft-tab-2">Channel Wise Sale</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#demo-lft-tab-3">Returns</a>
                </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
     <div class="tab-content">
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'sale' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}

   <div id="demo-lft-tab-1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <table data-toggle="table">
            <thead >
               <tr>
                  <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Day</th>
                  <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Sale Value</th>
                  <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Quantity Sold</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {% for day, val, qty in sale_data %}
               <tr>
                  <td>{{day}}</td>
                  <td>{{val}}</td>
                  <td>{{qty}}</td>
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>



<div id="demo-lft-tab-2" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <table data-toggle="table" >
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Channel</th>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Brand</th>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Category</th>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Selling Price</th>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Quantity Sold</th>
               <th data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Percentage %</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            {% for channel,brand,category,selling_price,quantity_sold, percentage in sal_data %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{channel}}</td>
               <td>{{brand}}</td>
               <td>{{category}}</td>
               <td>{{selling_price}}</td>
               <td>{{quantity_sold}}</td>
               <td>{{percentage}}%</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>

<!--   here is more code for other tab same as above  -->
<!--  -->


</form>


</div>
```

But when render data is large then page load takes more time.

Now I want know, How to load the data only for active tab ?

Comment: You can use an ajax call to load the active tab by placing a click listener on the tab links.

Comment: @BasvanStein I am new to front end can you suggest me any link or tutorial where i get exactly what I want.

Comment: I think this is a good one to start with: http://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/

Comment: @BasvanStein But I cant use php

Comment: Aah ok, but that does not matter much, you can use any server side language you want. Just make sure it returns the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
    $('#tab-nav > a').one('click', function() {
        // event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + target + "_content .filter_importance .menu div:last-of-type").trigger('click'); // here you can simplify by the use the `load` function instead of triggering a `click` event. 
    });
```

**How it works:**

1. I use SemanticUI for my CSS framework and `#tab-nav > a` targets the tabs. Following my naming policy, in each tab I have also added ID attribute, for instance `id="firsttab"`.
2. The DIVs with content all have ID attribute, for instance `id="firsttab_content"`. Please note how the target element is defined with the use of `target` variable: `$("#" + target + "_content .filter_importance .menu div:last-of-type")` produces `#firsttab_content`.
3. Inside the content of the tab I have buttons which use jQuery's `load` function to load the data.
4. The above solution clicks on one of the buttons - `trigger('click')`.

**Notes:** 
1. if you use `one('click', function()` the content will be loaded only once.
If you modify the code and make `on('click', function()` (pay attention to `e` one --> on), the content would be loaded each time you click on the tab.

2. if you want to set a certain tab as default and load the content inside it, put the `trigger('click') inside the

   $("document").ready(function() {
   });
3. You can decide on which content should be preloaded with this code:

   $("document").ready(function() {

   ```
   // loads content for tab open on page load
   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1); // gets the value of hash from URL
   $("#" + hash + "_content .filter_importance .menu div:last-of-type").trigger('click'); // targets and clicks the button which loads data inside the tab content area.
   ```

   });

Be advised that you might want to activate the tab with additional code - I do it by reading hash from URL in my backend. Usually it is done by adding class `active` to the element, in this case `"#firsttab a"`.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of any backend languages or the frameworks you user, browser understands only **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript**. It seems that you are developing application in Python with Django web framework.

You can follow below approaches to improve your page load and end user experiences,

- **Show Only Minimum & Important Data** - Only render minimal information from server side where ever user's eyes first look into it when the page is loaded.
- **Other Parts Can Be Empty** - Have a place holder(i.e empty tab pages) to fill the data later when page loaded into the browser.
- **Use Ajax** - Once page loaded in browser give an Ajax call to load the data.
- **Loading ...** - Meantime you can show some information saying "Loading ..." or animated images to inform the user about data loading.
- **Use Client Side Javascript MVC Frameworks** - Instead of rendering everything in server side, you can move most of the rendering task to client side using client side JavaScript MVC frameworks such as [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/), etc.
- **Pre-aggregate Large Dataset** - Sometimes, it is good to load pre-aggregated data for the first time. When user clicks further, you can display detailed information specific to user's interest.
- **Use Pagination** - If you are going to show data in a table, only retrieve and show a limited number of rows using pagination approach like, *how Google search result is displayed*
- **Google's - Make the Web Faster** - Finally, to speed up and optimize your web app's performance follow [Google's - Make the Web Faster](https://developers.google.com/speed/) guide lines.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Spring Framework, then use Pagination concept.It will make sure that only required data needs to be fetched and will be fast